# Skipping min sale qty validation when adding product to cart?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Magento version 2.4.6

I am listening to the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event to modify the price of a product when it is added to the cart. That works just fine.

Now, if the product has a min sale qty set, I want to skip that validation and add the product to the cart with qty 1. The `checkout_cart_product_add_after` is too late for that, so I guess I need another event where I can access the quote item.

I tried several events, no one had the quiet item available using `$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');` or `$item = $observer->getQuoteItem()`.

Any idea how to solve that?

Thanks